# How-to: This block can only be used once

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Probably a dumb question but not getting answers anywhere... I'm getting an error:
"How-to: This block can only be used once." 
from a yoast seo plugin but is this a limitation imposed by wp or yoast?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't put restrictions on third-party blocks. The only way to ensure a block can be added only once per post (or Page, or CPT) is when registering it - meaning the restriction was added by Yoast.

You could look into modifying the block yourself but there is usually a good reason when an author specifies the block can only be added once. Perhaps there is built-in Schema or it is coded in such a way that it wouldn't make sense to have more than one per page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
I was able to add the 2nd block in manually to keep the overall flow of the page intact in this instance but will keep this in mind for the future. :D